# Fetching data after left join query by removing duplicates?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I used a left join query with two tables so I'm getting multiple values for the main table column value in the resultset.  How can I remove duplicates in that?

Query:

```
SELECT cc.CCODE, cc.CNAME, rc.RCODE, rc.RNAME
  FROM RCODE AS rc 
  LEFT JOIN CCODE AS cc ON cc.RCODE = rc.RCODE
 GROUP BY cc.ccode
```

For `rc.RCODE` I get duplicate values if there is more than 1 entry for this in the child table. Once I get the resultset, how can I remove that in code level?

first table -->RCODE INDIA PAKISTAN AMERICA second table --> RCODE CCODE INDIA KERALA INDIA KARNATAKA AMERICA TEMP I need to get INDIA ->and its CCODE ANERICA its CCODE PAKISTAN its CCODE -> if its null ok ineed to get RCODE

Comment: please tune your query or provide your query and tables data.we can try.

Comment: If duplication is your problem why don't you apply primary key or unique index on columns on which you don't want duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not as clear as it could be, but if you want to have one row in the result set for each row in the RCode table, with at most one row of information from the CCode table, then you should write your query to generate exactly what you want rather than tinkering with the result set after fetching the data.  Since you need one row from CCode table per RCode value, we can use:

```
SELECT cc.CCode, cc.CName, rc.RCode, rc.RName
  FROM RCode AS rc
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT c1.CCode, c1.RCode, c1.CName
               FROM CCode AS c1
               JOIN (SELECT c2.RCode, MAX(c2.CCode) AS CCode
                       FROM CCode AS c2
                      GROUP BY c2.RCode) AS c3
                 ON c1.CCode = c3.CCode AND c1.RCode = c3.RCode
            ) AS cc
    ON cc.RCode = rc.RCode
```

The innermost sub-query (tagged c3) gives you the maximum CCode for each RCode in the CCode table.  When this is joined with the CCode table, it gives you the corresponding CName too.  This result set (tagged cc) is left outer joined with the RCode table, but there is at most one row in the cc result set for each RCode unless it so happens that the CCode tables contains several rows with the same RCode and the maximum CCode value.  If that is a problem, then you need to find an alternative mechanism to give you one row from the CCode table per RCode value (maybe `MAX(CName)` instead of `MAX(CCode)`).

Comment: hi thankx, but i need for each Rcode how many CCode r there in the sub table.

Comment: For each primary kry Rcode in main table how many foriegn key data in sub table i need to get -> For INDIA -> RCODe INDIA -> CCODE can be->kerala,karnataka,bengal for AMERICA-> there can be none CCODe

Comment: So count them...what is the COUNT aggregate for?  And please clarify the question to explain what you really need - exactly what you need - because it is far from clear that you need a count given the description of the question.  It also isn't clear which CName value(s) you might need, nor why you need the CCode values if you're really only counting how many there are.  Also, with LEFT OUTER JOIN, you'll be in danger of counting 1 when there are 0 rows in the CCode table for the given RCode.

Comment: first table -->RCODE    

INDIA
PAKISTAN
AMERICA

second table -->
RCODE  CCODE
INDIA  KERALA
INDIA  KARNATAKA
AMERICA  TEMP


I need to get INDIA ->and its CCODE
ANERICA its CCODE
PAKISTAN its CCODE -> if its null ok ineed to get RCODE